# Images from facebook album

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook

I am implementing an iPhone App where I have to retrieve images from facebook album and show these pics as a gallery in an app. I have this link  http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.457557810958775.98938.425513680829855&type=3 for where I have to fetch all images from album. I tried GrabKit from github for this but not helpful for me because it have multiple configuration like Picasa, Instagram, flicker etc.. but I want only for facebook...

Please if any one has an Idea or suggestion about it... then most appreciated....

Comment: Plz see my answer...without ay third party ....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30207465/ios-facebook-album-photos-picker/31789234#31789234

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to retrieve the images of a public album, then don't use GrabKit. GrabKit is made to retrieve the albums of the current logged user (on various platform as you mentioned) but not from public albums as you seem to wish.

I suggest you to use Facebook iOS SDK only. 
Read their "get started" tutorial ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/3.1/ ) and once you've figured out how to make a request to facebook, have a look to their Graph API ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ ) and specially the page about "Album" ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/ )

I hope this helps :)

Pierre-Olivier Simonard - Developer of GrabKit